# React App - Chrome Disk Cache JS file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using hash to generate the JS filename when I execute the deployment. But, the browser don't update the cache. (After deployment I need ask to customer to clear the cache and refresh the page)

In network tab it loads the main.f1e0597b.js
[image]

But, in the page source the file is other, main.52031433.js (the correct one).
[image]

Why it happens?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure of which file the page is loading?

Comment: Maybe inspect the network request for the .html page to make sure that's how it comes in.

Comment: In the network tab the html file is different from what is displayed when I click on "see page source" .... If I clear the cache the page works ok. But the problem is to do this after each deployment.

Comment: @BrunoQuaresma can you post your config code?

Comment: I found the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I pass an expire header to html files when sync with my as3 bucket.

**Problem:**

```
aws s3 sync $folder s3://$bucket --exclude '*.js' --exclude '*.css' --acl public-read --expires '2018-06-14T00:00:00Z'
```

**Correct:**

```
aws s3 sync $folder s3://$bucket --exclude '*.js' --exclude '*.css' --acl public-read
```